# What could be the reasons for not receiving messages in RabbitMQ?

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq

This is my first time testing RabbitMQ with node.js, and I utilized amqplib.

First, I run the

> node ./messages/consumer.js

and out put as follow -:

- Connected to RabbitMQ
- Channel created
- Waiting for messages...

Second, I run the

> node ./messages/producer.js

and out put as follow -:

- Connected to RabbitMQ
- Channel created
- Message sent: Hello, world!
- Connection to RabbitMQ closed

From the RabbitMQ management console, I observed the presence of test_exchange, test_queue, and test_key, but there was no information regarding any messages. And the consumer terminal did not log any indication of receiving a message. It still displays the message "Waiting for message.". Could you kindly inform me of where I may have overlooked this information?

//config.js

```
module.exports = {
    rabbitmq: {
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 5672,
      username: 'guest',
      password: 'guest',
      vhost: '/',
      exchange: 'test_exchange',
      queue: 'test_queue',
      routingKey: 'test_key'
    }
  }
```

//rabbitmq.js

```
const amqp = require("amqplib");
const config = require("../config/config");

class RabbitMQ {
  constructor() {
    this.connection = null;
    this.channel = null;
  }

  async connect() {
    try {
      const { host, port, username, password, vhost } = config.rabbitmq;
      this.connection = await amqp.connect(
        `amqp://${username}:${password}@${host}:${port}/${vhost}`
      );
      console.log("Connected to RabbitMQ");
      return this.connection;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error connecting to RabbitMQ", error);
    }
  }

  async createChannel() {
    try {
      if (!this.connection) {
        await this.connect();
      }
      this.channel = await this.connection.createChannel();
      console.log("Channel created");
      return this.channel;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error creating channel", error);
    }
  }

  async close() {
    try {
      await this.connection.close();
      console.log("Connection to RabbitMQ closed");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error closing connection to RabbitMQ", error);
    }
  }
}

module.exports = new RabbitMQ();
```

//producer.js

```
const rabbitmq = require('../lib/rabbitmq');
const config = require('../config/config');

async function produceMessage(message) {
  try {
    const channel = await rabbitmq.createChannel();
    const exchange = config.rabbitmq.exchange;
    const queue = config.rabbitmq.queue;
    const key = config.rabbitmq.routingKey;

    await channel.assertExchange(exchange, 'direct', { durable: true });
    await channel.assertQueue(queue, { durable: true });
    await channel.bindQueue(queue, exchange, key);

    const messageBuffer = Buffer.from(message);
    await channel.publish(exchange, key, messageBuffer);
    console.log(`Message sent: ${message}`);
    await rabbitmq.close();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error producing message', error);
  }
}

produceMessage('Hello, world!');
```

//consumer.js

```
const rabbitmq = require('../lib/rabbitmq');
const config = require('../config/config');

async function consumeMessage() {
  try {
    const channel = await rabbitmq.createChannel();
    const exchange = config.rabbitmq.exchange;
    const queue = config.rabbitmq.queue;
    const key = config.rabbitmq.routingKey;

    await channel.assertExchange(exchange, 'direct', { durable: true });
    await channel.assertQueue(queue, { durable: true });
    await channel.bindQueue(queue, exchange, key);

    channel.consume(queue, (msg) => {
      console.log(`Message received: ${msg.content.toString()}`);
      channel.ack(msg);
    }, { noAck: false });

    console.log('Waiting for messages...');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error consuming message', error);
  }
}

consumeMessage();
```

Comment: Do you see the message in the queue in `ready state`?

Comment: No. It is empty

Comment: I tried your code. The producer is not able to send the message because you're closing the connection immediately. I commented the connection close line in producer and I was able to receive the message in rabbitmq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem:**

Your message is failing to send because you are closing the connection immediately after executing the `publish` command. You can try this by commenting the line `await rabbitmq.close();` in `producer.js`.

---

**Solution:**

If you want to close the connection after sending the message. You can create `confirm channel` instead of a normal channel, which will allow you to receive `send` acknowledgment.

**1. Channel Creation**

Change the channel creation line in `rabbitmq.js` file:

```
this.channel = await this.connection.createConfirmChannel();
```

**2. Producer:**

In the `producer.js`, call `waitForConfirms` function before closing the connection:

```
await channel.waitForConfirms();
await rabbitmq.close();
```